# maximum length of a longvarchar - Genexus 8 C#/Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, genexus

What is the maximum length of a `LongVarChar` variable in GeneXus 8?
I am using C# Oracle platform.

Comment: wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7371,LongVarChar says it maps to an oracle LONG which is 2GB on a  oracle 11.

Comment: You should [avoid](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1831) the Oracle LONG datatype at nearly all costs.

Comment: @jeff6times7 is right, `LONG` columns have been obsolete for years and are nothing but trouble. However it doesn't seem that Genexus has any support for the more modern `CLOB` type.

Answer (score 1):

GeneXus 8.0 creates LongVarChar as LONG in Oracle (by default).
GeneXus 9.0 or higher create LongVarChar fields as CLOB in Oracle 8 or higher (by default).

There is a workaround in GeneXus 8.0 (Java Generator Upgrade 8) to create the LongVarChar field as CLOB: Create a config.gx file in your Knowledge Base directory or GeneXus installation Directory with the following content: LongVarCharAsOracleLong=n and generate code again.
With that setting, GeneXus creates tables and generate programs using CLOB.
More information at [SAC 18551](https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?,,,18551).

Answer (score 0):

According to [GeneXus 8.0 documentation](http://library.gxtechnical.com/gxdlsp/pub/home.htm?/genexus_8.0_help_system/data_types/longvarchar_data_type.htm), the maximum length of a `LongVarChar` should be 32MB.

Anyway, the `LongVarChar` is defined as a `Long` in Oracle. You should check Oracle's limits for that data type.